# "Directional" conductivity in linear flux-potential laws?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction, porous-media

**Question**: Has the notion of "directional conductivity" been defined and used in the study of heat flow and electric current flow?

**Context**: The table below gives three laws that describe linear flux-potential relationships.  As seen, a correspondence exist between the hydraulic conductivity $K$, thermal conductivity $\lambda$, and electrical conductivity $\sigma$.

[image]

In the study of fluid flow through porous media, there is this notion of "directional conductivity".  For an isotropic medium, the velocity vector $(\vec v)$ and the potential gradient vector $(\nabla \Phi)$ are co-linear.  Because the two vectors are co-linear we ordinarily do not specify whether the hydraulic conductivity $(K)$ is in the direction of flow or in the direction of the potential gradient.  For an anisotropic medium, in general, the velocity vector and the potential gradient vector are not co-linear.  The concept of directional hydraulic conductivity seeks to extend the definition of hydraulic conductivity.  Accordingly, the directional conductivity in the direction of flow is defined as
$$\tag{1} K_{df}=\frac{|\vec v|}{|\nabla \Phi| \cos \alpha}$$
where $|\nabla \Phi| \cos \alpha$ is the component of the potential gradient vector that is co-linear with the velocity vector.  Similarly, the directional conductivity in the direction of the potential gradient is defined by
$$\tag{2} K_{dp}=\frac{|\vec v|\cos \alpha}{|\nabla \Phi|}$$
where $|\vec v|\cos \alpha$ is the component of the velocity vector that is co-linear with the potential gradient vector.

**Expanded Question**: So I am curious to know if the notion of a "directional thermal and/or electrical conductivity" has been defined and used in the study of heat flow and/or electric current flow.  If "yes", how has it been utilized to help solve problems?  Also, how would one go about measuring these separate and distinct values?